# Keypress event stuck in infinite loop

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a button that when pressed 'enter' would display a MessageBox and if you pressed enter again to close the MessageBox, it would go into an infinite loop. How do I ignore firing multiple key up event on the MessageBox?

```
this.okButton.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(this.okButton_KeyUp);

private void okButton_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Handled) { return; }
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter && okButton.Enabled)
    {
        okButton_Click(null, null);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}

private void okButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Hello World", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
}
```

Comment: Just get rid of the KeyUp code.  Pressing Enter on a button will call the click event for you.

Comment: I'm not understanding the infinite loop problem. Can you show the loop?

Comment: @Chipster Run the code, it keeps popping up the MessageBox.

Comment: Pressing enter on a button does not call the click event for me as the button is in a user control

Comment: Then maybe you should be documenting your question better.

Comment: If the button has focus, always pressing enter or space raise click event. If it doesn't have focus, then will not receive `KeyUp` as well. The question is unclear to me.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite the desired behavior. What happens is,

1. During the Key Down event, Message Box gets closed.
2. During Key Up event, the Message Box is opened again.

What you can do here is remove the KeyUp event of Button and instead rely on Click event directly. Everytime you click Enter with focus on Button, the Click event would fire.

This will ensure you get the desired behavior.